# Cómo realizar llamada a API para no recibir por respuesta 401 o´ 403 (errores)

Tags: python, scraping

Buenas tardes a tod@s.

Estoy intentanto recibir respuesta json de la siguiente dirección (https://www.vinted.es/api/v2/promoted_closets?closet_count=1&item_count=5&exclude_member_ids=&catalog_ids=&status_ids=&size_ids=&color_ids=&brand_ids=&material_ids=&search_text=pandora&search_session_id=9917a2cb-c830-4c05-bde1-bcfe17b7e168), entiendo que es una llamada a API de esta aplicación.
Puedo ver su contenido directamente en la pantalla, pero cuando intento automatizar para extraer información me es imposible. Agradecería me pudieran orientar de cómo enfocarlo.

```
import requests

import json

url = "https://www.vinted.es/api/v2/promoted_closets?closet_count=1&item_count=5&exclude_member_ids=&catalog_ids=&status_ids=&size_ids=&color_ids=&brand_ids=&material_ids=&search_text=pandora&search_session_id=8a0aeb53-57a2-47df-9fa8-152b85b798f6"

# cabeceras de la petición HTTP
headers={'content-type':'application/json',
     'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

data = requests.get(url)
# contenido_json = data.json()
# print(contenido_json)
print(data.status_code)
```

Me devuelve error 403. He de indicar otros datos en Cabecera, buscar un token???

Comment: Me retorna "invalid_authentication_token" y "code: 100".

Comment: Te hace falta el token de autorización. El código 403 en una respuesta http se refiere a que el acceso al recurso solicitado no ha sido permitido por el servidor. Es un tema de autorización y / o autenticación.

Comment: Si agarras la url y la pegas en el navegador tira codigo 100 pero en `message` te da `Token d'authentification invalide`

Comment: En el Encabezado de Solicitud tengo lo siguiente: x-csrf-token: mFfU4n4c84yFMHxQqCfEhtpL2A8EJnmvNbEvOdasxRoOrTR6P_4wtHgM7q8jluPUb0USVN18QeOoWTSu0xKxlw.        ¿Con eso se puede hacer algo? ¿O necesito autorización del administrador?

Comment: Donde conseguiste ese token?

Comment: Realizando una inspección en el html. Me voy a conexiones y ahí en el encabezado de solicitud (de la petición)

Comment: Pero no se dónde y cómo habría que colocarlo en mi código de Python